# Is there a need to test execute() result in PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I usually use the following statement for pdo MySQL queries

```
$query = $db->prepare('MySQL statement');
$result = $query->execute(array())

Then use $query->fetch or fetchcolumn (to check Count(*)) to fetch data.
```

My question is - is there a need to test whether $result is true or not? In a productive environment if MySQL is down error will exist when we declare new PDO.

Under what circumstances do I need to test whether execute is true or false?

Comment: So it's safe I can skip testing whether execute returns true or false? The post doesn't answer the question. I know how to fetch and test whether data exist using COUNT.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE`, as explained in the [Errors and error handling](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) chapter.

If you configure PDO to throw exceptions (`PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`) then no, PDO will automatically throw an exception on error.

In any other case (use the default PDO connection options or explicitly set `PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT` or `PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING`) then yes, you need to verify manually the success of each individual operation.

*It isn't useful that `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` is not the default but, you know, PHP has a history of hiding helpful error messages for some misguided user-friendliness.*

Comment: The answer I need. Thank you.

Comment: @DaveTeu just a note for you. Despite that most internet articles say, do not catch this exception right in place, but let it bubble up to the handler.

Comment: I catches pdo exception at declaration and just inform user that update is not available at the moment and try again. And send a email to me so I can fix t on my end. I guess if DB cannot be connected or returning error, there's no point going down to the handler. Query wise I will have to ensure queries are all without error before it goes into productive environment. I can't have any queries returning errors, it should either return something or let me know there's no results. I think.

Comment: @DaveTeu so you are doing it for the every update, which is very inefficient. this is why you need a single handler to tell a user to try again for any query. But it is up to you. If you like to write a lot of repetitive code, then keep with catching at declaration. And you know, when a query return no results it is not an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the query passed for example is the most common.

If `$result` is false, that means the query did not pass and there is error in the `$query` which later you may want to check out.

You may create some login where you check if `$result` is false and throw some prepared exception, or structure your application with it.

Basically if `$result` is false, you may create some custom logic for it.

Comment: So in productive environment where we verified all the MySQL statements correct I can safely remove the test for $result?

Comment: Because in productive environment I don't think we can have any fail queries.

Comment: @DaveTeu in fact, there are many error types other than syntax errors. And yes, errors happen in prod environment too, so you WILL have failed queries. But manual checking is not needed anyway, as it was explained in the other answer.